# What are the seven wisdoms?

Tags: sources-mekorot, mysticism-kabbalah, biography

I've read several biographies where the author will say that "this person was an expert in the seven wisdoms". Well, I'd like to know if any of y'all can help me out by explaining to me what are these seven wisdoms? Thank you.

Comment: Can you please explain the relevance to Judaism?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen this question here before.

Comment: Sure. While I was reading biographies on Rabbi Nachman Of Breslov, and coming across other gedolim in various books, they mentioned this concept of 7 wisdoms one can be an expert in. So I'd like to know what are these 7 wisdoms... @Dr.Shmuel

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include all information you already know about this that can help people help you find an answer. Examples might be when or about whom the biographies were written. Comments are ephemeral by design and can be deleted at any time. Also note that, as stated now, the question seems to have no connection to Judaism; I'm closing it as off-topic for now for that reason, but the closure can be easily reversed if you do in fact have a Judaism-related question: for example, if you think these wisdoms have something to do with Judaism.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for, which had everything to do with Judaism and Judiasm only. 1) Tevunah, the ability to understand and draw conclusions.
2) The knowledge of nature - in subjects like chemistry and physics.
3) The knowledge of the soul – or as Rav Aharon puts it, the study of psychology.
4) The knowledge of biology
5) Music
6) Metaphysics… (philosophy)  and
7) The knowledge of Torah …. which is the most significant branch.
And all that can be found here - http://haemtza.blogspot.com/2013/05/the-seven-branches-of-wisdom.html?m=1       Thanks

Comment: http://text.rcarabbis.org/abrabanel-the-menora-an-early-interpretation-supporting-the-concept-of-tora-u’madda-by-yaakov-bieler/

Comment: I think that there is an issue with the 7 qane hamenora in Maharal

Comment: There are several views on what specifically the 7 categories of (secular) wisdom are. But Soleveichick’s listing is fine. He includes Torah wisdom as part of them in his Bar Mitzvah talk. He uses the analogy of the lamps of the menorah. Most examples that I have seen use the analogy of the ladder of Yaacov’s dream for this, like the Maharal of Prague.